# is it safe to delete a constraint from sysconstraints (because "drop constraint" fails)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

when I run this SQL:

```
IF EXISTS
(select a.id, a.name ,b.name
from sysobjects a, sysobjects b, sysconstraints c
where a.name = 'my_index_name'
  and b.name = 'my_table'
  and a.id = c.constid
  and c.id = b.id) 
  BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE my_table
    DROP CONSTRAINT my_index_name
  END
```

... it runs until canceled, at which point SSMS gives the error:

```
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 9
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
```

I tried altering the constraint to NOCHECK but it already is. I ran the existence-check part of the query separately, and the index does exist.

I have enough SQL knowledge to be able to delete the constraint from sysconstraints and sysobjects, but I wonder if that will corrupt my database (in particular, I wonder if SQL that later tries to re-create the same index name will fail due to leftover disk files/data managed by SQL Server).

Is there a way to actually "see previous errors" (since there are none visible in SSMS)?

Comment: You can't just delete rows from sysconstraints or sysobjects. Try it and you will get error 259. "Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.". We used to be able to do those updates but as of sql server 2005 they are no longer allowed.

Answer (score 0):

this question is moot, as Sean Lange points out:

Msg 259, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ad hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed.